# Binomial Distribution Compression

Tags: c++, opencl, probability, logical-operators, binomial-coefficients

I am currently have difficulty coming up with a fast and low memory solution for a problem. I am attempting to solve using the binomial distribution. I have a binomial distribution that can take on 5 values, the probabilities of the values occurring is 1/16, 4/16, 6/16, 4/16, 1/16. I am currently using a 4 bit number to access a binomial distribution array of size 16 that contains the 5 values with occurrences proportional to their probabilities. Is there a way to compress the array to size 5 and still be able to quickly determine which element in the array to access. I considered using a Karnaugh map however the number of logical operations required slowed the entire process down. Is there some sort of compression or technique that exists to rapidly implement this, as I wish to increase the size of the binomial distribution, which is currently infeasible due to the increase in either memory or computation time.

```
  binomialCoefficients[16]= {v1, v2, v2, v2, v2, v3, v3, v3, v3, v3, v3, v3, v4, v4, v4, v4, v5};
  for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
     uint random = MWC64X(&seed2);
     currentValue = currentValue * binomialCoefficients[random & 0b1111];
  }
```

VS

```
 binomialCompressed[5]={v1,v2,v3,v4,v5};
 for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    uint random = MWC64X(&seed2);
    bool A = (random & 0b1000) >>3;
    bool B = (random & 0b0100) >>2; 
    bool C = (random & 0b0010) >>1; 
    bool D = (random & 0b0001); 
    uint logicMappedIndex = (A&B&C&D)<<2 + (A&!B|...)<<1 +...;
    currentValue = currentValue * binomialCompressed[logMappedIndex];
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify if you always have p=1/2?

Comment: The probability is always p=0.5 , I have found a better way of approaching this problem but is based on a completely different distribution. I am curious still though as to whether this problem is solvable.

Comment: If your input is uniformly distributed, I would look at further compression. Factor p^N is always constant, so I would move it out. Then I would basically compress Pascal triangle further by using only left off its vertical axis, see http://www.mathsisfun.com/pascals-triangle.html. So instead of 5 you need array of 3 with values 1, 4, 6 and bits split 2, 8, 6. So the only open question left is how to convert such bits split into algorithm

Comment: Sadly the input is log-normally distributed. I think that the method you've presented would indeed work for a uniformly distributed problem though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate a random number, each of the bits has a probability of 1/2 of being a 1.
If you just count the bits, it is already giving you the index in your compressed array with binomial probabilities.

```
 binomialCompressed[5]={v1,v2,v3,v4,v5};
 for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
     uint random = MWC64X(&seed2) & 0b1111; //Get 4 bits only
     uint count = popcount(random);
     currentValue = currentValue * binomialCompressed[count];
 }
```